# AzCopy - include tables and queues

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I used the AzCopy command to backup a Blob to a another account.

I am rather new to Azure storage, what I really want to do it move the whole storage account.  This has Tables and Queues.

I am not clear is how dependent or independent the Tables and Queues are to the Blobs.  Is there a way to move the whole thing, or do I have to copy the blobs then recreate the Tables and Queus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. AzCopy supports copying Blobs from one account to another:

   ```
   AzCopy.exe /source:https://youraccount1.blob.core.windows.net/srccontainer /sourceKey:key1 /dest:https://youraccount2.blob.core.windows.net/destcontainer /destKey:key2 /s
   ```

   AzCopy by default uses server-side asynchronous copy, which doesn't have an SLA on copy speed. If you'd like to achieve consistent copy speed, please consider adding option /SyncCopy to the command line above. For further information of /SyncCopy, please refer to: [AzCopy – Introducing synchronous copy and customized content type](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/01/13/azcopy-introducing-synchronous-copy-and-customized-content-type.aspx).
2. AzCopy supports downloading a Table to local disk and uploading it to another account:

   ```
   AzCopy.exe /source:https://youraccount1.table.core.windows.net/srctable /sourceKey:key1 /dest:d:\localfolder /manifest:yourfilename /splitSize:128
   AzCopy.exe /source:d:\localfolder /dest:https://youraccount2.table.core.windows.net/desttable /destKey:key2 /manifest:yourfilename /entityOperation:InsertOrReplace
   ```

   If you'd like to achieve better table downloading performance and you do know how the partition keys are arranged in your source table, you can specify option /PKRS in the command line to download table.
3. AzCopy doesn't support copying Queues.

To download the latest version of AzCopy and find detailed information of AzCopy, please refer to http://aka.ms/azcopy .

Comment: thanks, so to recreate a Azure Storage on another account I would copy the blob and table with AzCopy and then just create a queue for each?

Comment: Yes, you have to create a queue for each that in the source account and write code to move messages to the target queue by yourself.

Comment: The blob copy works but the Table copy does not.  First the "/SplitSize:128" is not recognized.  So if I leave this command off, it says "The syntax of the command is incorrect.  The source azure storage location type can not be inferred. Use /sourceType:blob to specify the location type explicity

Comment: AzCopy does not include the support for copying tables to tables directly, you can export table to local file and import to a new table

Comment: The domain name I wrote was incomplete (missing "core.") and I've correct it. Please check again. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: About the unrecognized option "SplitSize", which version of AzCopy are you using? Only Preview version of AzCopy contains the functionalities to copy Azure Table, you can download the latest version 4.2 Preview from http://aka.ms/azcopy

Comment: sorry I have been away.

Comment: Wanted to mention that `azcopy` on linux only supports `blob` and `file`. I'm using `6.0.0-netcorepreview` and it cannot download `table`.